# What is Firebase using under the hood?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am planning to use a BaaS for a project, and am almost convinced to use Firebase.

The only thing I am wondering about it is what is it using as database?

I know that it is a noSQL database, storing element in JSON, [a question on quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-firebase-still-use-MongoDB) mentionned that Firebase once used MongoDB as it s database, but not anymore.

So my question is simply: What is Firebase is using under the hood to store it's data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was just poking around on the interwebz and found this, before read your question:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Doi4MP_A81k

> 2. The backend is proprietary.  Since our data structure (a JSON-based tree) is pretty unique, it's pretty custom.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is a really clean and complete answer, welcome to stack overflow :)